# Did Ghost Whisperer reference Charmed?

Tags: charmed, ghost-whisperer

Binge watching [*Ghost Whisperer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_Whisperer) recently, and Season 4, Episode 3 ([*Ghost in the Machine*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1256159/)) revolves around an online social simulation where avatars interact much as they do in real life.

During one description scene in the beginning, there is a reference to a group of girls that go to the private "[Halliwell Academy](https://charmed.fandom.com/wiki/Halliwell_Academy)", which was a school for magical students established by the Charmed Ones from the series [Charmed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charmed).

Charmed does predate Ghost Whisperer, however they were shown on different networks, and had different creators. Is there any evidence that this was a purposeful nod, or just a coincidence?